# where is the shared folder in linux inside Vmware Player?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shared-folders, vmware-player

I'm trying to write a program which will copy files from my guest OS which is linux Ubunto to my host OS which is windows 7. I have enabled the shared folders options but of course in order to copy files, i need to write a destination path in my code and I don't know where is the shared folder located inside Linux... so does someone knows where it's located?

Answer (score 8):

First you need to configure the shared folders in VMware Player, as you said you've done.  Let's assume you named the shared folder `Shared`.  Then, on the linux guest, add a line like the following to `/etc/fstab`:

```
.host:/Shared    /mnt/C    vmhgfs    user    0 0
```

This will make the host folder that you named `Shared` accessible as the directory `/mnt/C` on the linux guest.

You'll need to create the mount point on the guest manually:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/C
```

Finally, restart the linux guest.

Comment: what do i need to write instead of ".host"? when i tried it i got .host/C no such file or directory

Comment: You need `.host:/` followed by the name you gave to the folder in the VMware Player configuration.

Comment: sorry to bother you but it seems to be giving the same message again. Is there something wrong with what i wrote (SharedLinuxFolder is the name i gave to the shared folder in the vmware configuration): yonatan@ubunto:~$ .host/SharedLinuxFolder /mnt/SharedLinuxFolder vmhgfs yonatan 0 0

Comment: You need to _add the line to `/etc/fstab`_ -- it's not a command.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you very much. It didn't work for me at first since i didn't have vmware tools installed and after i installed it i could find the shared folder which is located at /mnt/hgfs

Answer (score 7):

The shared folders you add to the VMWare player Virtual Machine Settings > Options tab, under "Folders"

[image: VMWare Player Shared Folder Settings]

are available in the guest OS at:

```
/mnt/hgfs/<folder_name>
```

In this case, I access the folder named "shared" using the path:

```
/mnt/hgfs/shared/
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing vms-tools, add the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
.host:/shared /mnt/hgfs vmhgfs defaults,ttl=5,uid=1000,gid=1000   0 0
```

(given that the shared foler name in VMWare Player settings is `/shared`)